# Load javascript after the page loads completely in joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have JavaScript code I want to add my website in Joomla, using this module: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-javascript
The problem is that until you load the javascript code (which is a banner) page not displayed.

How do I can load the code after the page is loaded?

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var var1 = "728";
  var var2 = "90";
  var var3 = "728x90";
  var var4 = "9832";
  var var5 = "d08726019e4a2a15cb1d49092e4d0522";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.adshexa.com/show_ads.php"></script>
```

I've seen these lines of code , but do not work. I can not write well or put them in the right place

```
document.onload = function 
window.onload = function
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript that executes after page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)?

Comment: I am a newbie, do not really know how to add it. Try lines of code , but add in the part of the module where I have to put the script does not work. Do not know if I 'm doing well ...

Comment: @nicael This does not answer the quest for Joomla